# Cannot convert value of type 'NSObject -> () -> ViewController' to expected argument type 'AnyObject?'

Tags: swift, uipangesturerecognizer

I am trying to declare a gesture recogniser. When I declare it in the function it works fine but when I declare at the class level so it is available to multiple functions I get the error.

> Cannot convert value of type 'NSObject -> () -> ViewController' to expected argument type 'AnyObject?'

I am declaring it like this:

```
let gestureBack = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("wasDraggedBack:"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want `Gesture` object available to multiple function than declare its instance at class level and initialize the object in `viewDidLoad` like this.

```
var gestureBack: UIPanGestureRecognizer?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.gestureBack = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("wasDraggedBack:"))
}
```

Comment: awesome thanks that was what I need to solve it appreciate you taking the time. All these people rate down and don't even bother to help. It is appreciated that you made the effort.

Comment: Note that this initializes the property twice. Alternatives are: an implicitly unwrapped optional, or a lazy property as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/27667190/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR Now is it ok :)?